# Is the "_" prefix reserved for MovieClip names?

Tags: flash, naming-conventions, actionscript-2, movieclip

Is it possible to use the **"_" underscore prefix** for your own **MovieClip names?** (AS2)

i.e. Can you name a created/attached MovieClip "_feature" or "_bug" ?

Typically this is reserved for **internal properties** like `_x` or `_visible`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "_" prefix has no technical significance - you can use it your own names for MovieClips, text fields, or any other variable or method you like.

As a convention, it used to be common for the names of "built in" properties (like `_x`, `_visible`, etc.) to begin with an underbar, but they stopped doing this around v6 or v7, so many later properties (`filters`, `transform` for example) don't use it. Also, they've used (and still use I believe, in AS3) multiple underbars for internal names they don't want people to trip over (like `__proto__`).

There also used to be a fairly widespread convention to prepend `$` to properties or methods intended to be private, since declaring them to be private doesn't have any effect. You see this a lot in components.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is fine. Not really sure you should be doing it but if you have a case for it it won't error out.  I tend to reserve _ to prefix private members of a class.

Comment: I asked whether you could name MOVIECLIPs with "_" not members! Sorry!

Comment: So what you actually meant was instance names not library symbols.  Easy mistake to make and yes, again that's also fine. Hardly feel like this was worth a down vote!

Comment: This did not deserve a -1, the poster answered your question and then made a recommendation based on best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to use MovieClip names like **_myclip**, you can reference it statically **`this._myclip`** or dynamically too. **`this["_"+"myclip"]`**

Comment: Why do you post an answer to your own question? It's more appropriate to edit the question and add an SOLVED: or UPDATE section to it.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, your participation on Stackoverflow is  just about gaining reputation?

Comment: Wrong, if my answer is the best, then I should checkmark it so others know that it is the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine, but proper as3 practice is to use the "*" for only internal, private/protected variables, and then write getters and setters without the "*".

eg:

```
private var _word:String = "something"

public function get word():String {
     return _word
}

public function set word(a_word:String):void {
     _word = a_word
}
```

A little verbose, but it makes for a nice API.